# How knockout know about data-binded object if it has only its name?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I have something like:

```
<form action='/someServerSideHandler'>
  <p>You have asked for <span data-bind='text: gifts().length'>&nbsp;</span> gift(s)</p>
  <table data-bind='visible: gifts().length > 0'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Gift name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th />
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: gifts'>
      <tr>
        <td><input class='required' data-bind='value: name, uniqueName: true' /></td>
        <td><input class='required number' data-bind='value: price, uniqueName: true' /></td>
        <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeGift'>Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button data-bind='click: addGift'>Add Gift</button>
  <button data-bind='enable: gifts().length > 0' type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and

```
var GiftModel = function(gifts) {
var self = this;
self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);

self.addGift = function() {
  self.gifts.push({
    name: "",
    price: ""
  });
};

self.removeGift = function(gift) {
  self.gifts.remove(gift);
};

self.save = function(form) {
  alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.gifts));
  // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.gifts);
};
};

var viewModel = new GiftModel([
    { name: "Tall Hat", price: "39.95"},
    { name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.00"}
]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// Activate jQuery Validation
$("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });
```

how it is happening that `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` is magically making biding by name of variable? Is knockout searching it somehow by name? How the template know that this is his array/data set? I am basically .net developer so in my mind taking something "by name" is not clear. Or maybe am I wrong that this is taken by name? I read documentation but I still do not get the way how knockout connect template gifts() with array named gifts from model?

but the way this is sample from knockout main page.

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Comment: Have you looked at the earlier examples, for instance [this one](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html)?  It shows how things are being bound by their object key names - the other examples just build up other functionality from there.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I know how to do it without a problem. But i like to know how it is working. It is like a car. I know how to drive a car, but also I like to know how it is working to eventually be able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how it is happening that ko.applyBindings(viewModel); is magically making biding by name of variable? Is knockout searching it somehow by name?

Cutting some corners here, but two things in which Javascript (not so much KO) differs from .NET, as related to your question:

- All members (e.g. `self.gifts`) can also be accessed as if `self` had a string based indexer to get them (e.g. `self['gifts']`);
- Javascript is dynamically typed, so `self['gifts']` can at run time contain an array, string, observable: whatever.

So, Knockout can take your string `"gifts"` use it to get to the variable `self["gifts"]` and at run time check for its type to see if it's an array, observable y/n, etc, and choose the appropriate code path accordingly.

As for your other question:

> How the template know that this is his array/data set?

Knockout is open source (though perhaps not easy to read when starting out with JS), and if you dive in to it you'll find that [`foreach` assumes it's passed an array](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/foreach.js).

Comment: Ok, so I have one more question. This object var GiftModel . Why I can see its properties outside the variable? Why I can call `self.Gifts` in console in, for example, chrome? In my `net` mind I would be albe to do same but with `GiftModel.self.gifts` or eventually `GiftModel.gifts` becouse selft is `this` ....

Comment: If you call `self.Gifts` in the console *while at a break point inside the function* your context will allow you to do so. If you do it outside of it, it shouldn't work tbh.